# Clamping to next lowest value in a series

Tags: algorithm, integer, series, integer-division, clamp

I'm trying to clamp a number to the lower value of a series of numbers. For instance, if I have a series (sorry for the bad notation)

`[pq]` where `p` is any integer and `q` is any positive number.

Say if `q is 50` my series will be `...-150, -100, -50, 0, 50, 100, 150...`

Now what I'd like is to have a function `f(y)` which'll clamp any number to the next lowest number in the series.

For example, if I had the number `37` I'd be expecting the `f(37) = 0` and I'd be expecting `f(-37) = -50`.

I've tried many algorithms involving modulus and integer division but I can't seem to figure it out. The latest I've tried is for example

`(37 / q) * q` which works great for positive numbers but doesn't work for any number between -50 and 0.

I've also tried `((37 - q) / q) * q` but this won't work for negative cases which land exactly in the series.

**EDIT**

Assume that I do not have the entire series but only the multiplier `p` of the series.

Comment: Can't you handle the difference between negative and positive numbers with an `if`?

Comment: @MarkRansom `if(x < 0 and x % q == 0), that would work but I wanna try a purely mathematical way. Is that possible?

Comment: No way I know of with integer division, but lets see if someone is more clever than me.

Comment: @Archmede: But what qualifies as "purely mathematical" and what doesn't? The expression you need is `f(y) = [y / q] * q`, where `[]` stands for "rounding towards negative infinity". Does such rounding qualify as "purely mathematical" or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to divide `y` by `q` using integer Euclidean division and then multiply the result by `q` again.

```
f(y) = (y / q) * q
```

where `/` represents Euclidean division.

In programming languages that do not immediately support Euclidean division you will have to either implement it manually or adjust the result of whatever division the language supports.

For example, in C and C++ Euclidean division for positive divisor `q` can be implemented through the native "Fortran-style" division as

```
 (y >= 0 ? y : y - q + 1) / q
```

so in C or C++ the whole expression will look as

```
f(y) = (y >= 0 ? y : y - q + 1) / q * q
```

For `37` you get

```
f(37) = 37 / 50 * 50 = 0
```

For `-37` you get

```
f(-37) = (-37 - 50 + 1) / 50 * 50 = -86 / 50 * 50 = -50
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a purely mathematical way, with no consideration given to computational efficiency, you could shift the input `p` into the positive integer range by adding a positive integer that is greater than or equal to `|p|` and is a multiple of `q`, and then shift it back by subtracting afterwards. `p^2*q` satisfies this.

This gives:
`((p + p^2*q) / q) * q - p^2*q`

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract the modulus result once you've ensured it's positive. In some languages it will *always* be positive, but if not:

```
mod = p % q
positive_mod = (mod + q) % q
answer = p - positive_mod
```

Result in C++: https://ideone.com/kIuit8

Result in Python: https://ideone.com/w6wUgZ